# Map<String, methodReference> - Run methodReference with arguments

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have tried to run the methods like this, but it didn't work.

My map with method references:

```
private final Map<String, Runnable> validationMethods = new HashMap<>();

{
  validationMethods.put("getTransactions", ValidationInterceptor::validateTransactions);
  validationMethods.put("getDeals", ValidationInterceptor::validateDeals);
}
```

Here's the methods I'm trying to run from the map:

```
private static void validateTransactions(Method method, List<Object> arguments, Object resourceInstance) {
    doSomthing(method, arguments, resourceInstance);
}

private static void validateDeals(Method method, List<Object> arguments, Object resourceInstance) {
    doSomthing(method, arguments, resourceInstance);
}
```

And the core method with parameters:

```
protected void handleValidation(final Message message, final Method method, final List<Object> arguments) {
    validationMethods.get(method.getName()).run();
}
```

Question is - how do I pass the arguments to the static methods?

Comment: Your `Map` values are `Runnable`, and as `run()` takes no parameters, you can't assign a method reference that takes parameters to it.

Answer (score 4):

Define [a functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Validator {
    void validate(Method method, List<Object> arguments, Object resourceInstance);
}
```

Change the type of the map to:

```
private final Map<String, Validator> validationMethods = new HashMap<>();
```

Call the method `validate` on a `Validator` retrieved from the map:

```
validationMethods.get(method.getName()).validate(method, arguments, message);
```

The problem is your static methods can't be represented as `Runnable`s: the method `run` doesn't have parameters (when you call `.run()` you don't pass arguments).

In the standard library, we don't have a function which would take 3 parameters and returns a value. If you reduced the number of parameters to 2, we could go with [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). If there were one parameter, [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) would come in handy. That's why declaring own functional interface here is justified.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you use `Method` to define the required validation rule. So you should have an interface with the required method and number of parameters:

@FunctionalInterface
interface ValidationRule {

```
// add as many parameters as you need
void validate(Message message, List<Object> arguments);
```

}

Then it's better to encapsulate each validation in the separate class. It helps you to test and support each of them:

```
public final class GetTransactionsValidationRule implements ValidationRule {

    @Override
    public void validate(Message message, List<Object> arguments) {
        // logic validation
    }
}

public final class GetDealsValidationRule implements ValidationRule {

    @Override
    public void validate(Message message, List<Object> arguments) {
        // logic validation
    }
}
```

And finally should have encapsulated basic validation logic in another class:

```
public class ValidationService {

    private static final ValidationRule NULL = (message, arguments) -> {};

    private final Map<String, ValidationRule> rules = new HashMap<>();

    {
        rules.put("getTransactions", new GetTransactionsValidationRule());
        rules.put("getDeals", new GetDealsValidationRule());
    }

    public void handleValidation(Message message, Method method, List<Object> arguments) {
        rules.getOrDefault(method.getName()).validate(arguments);
    }

}
```

All you need now is just create an instance of `ValidationService` and call `handleValidation` method:

```
ValidationService validationService = new ValidationService();
validationService.handleValidation(...);
```